# scrapy crawl multiple page using Request

Tags: python, request, web-crawler, scrapy

I followed the [document](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

But still not be able to crawl multiple pages.

My code is like:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for thing in response.xpath('//article'):
            item = MyItem()
            request = scrapy.Request(link,
                                     callback=self.parse_detail)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

def parse_detail(self, response):
        print "here\n"
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['test'] = "test"
        yield item
```

Running this code will not call parse_detail function and will not crawl any data. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find if I comment out allowed_domains it will work. But it doesn't make sense because  link is belonged to allowed_domains for sure.